# can anyone tell me when to use navigatorKey instead of Navigator.of(build context) in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Currently I'm using `navigatorKey` for the first time to remove a dialog

```
 

    Future signIn() async {
    // to show user a loading dialog while logging in
        showDialog(
          context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) => const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
        try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email.text.trim(),
            password: password.text.trim(),
          );
        } catch (e) {
          print(
            e.toString(),
          );
        }
        /* Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
         does not work */
        navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
        // to remove the loading dialog now ,after user is signed in
```

this works fine but I'm confused in when to use navigator key instead of

```
Navigator.of(build context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make global **navigatorKey**

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Befor using it, assign this navigator key to **MaterialApp**

```
MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey, //here
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,but i know it and did already the same,all i want to know is that why can't i use "navigator.of(context)" here

Comment: if you want to use Navigation outside of build context , u can use navigator key for that purpose otherwise using navigator.of(context) is fine.